# Angular2 subscribe non number parametr from URL

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have issue with subscribe a non numeric parametr from url. Local variable inside lambda `params => {}` can be only number? My Code:

```
getRecordDetail() {
        this.sub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
            params => {
                if (params[ 'id' ] != undefined) {
                    let id = +params[ 'id' ]
                    console.log('ID: ', id);


                } else console.log("UNDEFINED ASSETID");
            }
        );
    }
```

Why `let id` always has type number? How can I get String parametr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
+params[ 'id' ]
```

putting **+** in front of variable is equal to `parseInt(params[ 'id' ])`

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `+` operator, It a way to convert a variable to `Number`

```
let id = params['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ehh, My bad, `+=` gives a type number, if `let xxx = params[ 'id' ]` then can be passed any type of variable.